# 3D animation on a view with OpenGL

Tags: android

I want to make an animation on a **CardView** but this will be 3D . With OpenGL ES graphic drawing with renderer but I will not draw anything , can I use OpenGL on **CardView**,if it's not how can I make this?

Comment: Create `GLSurfaceView`, and add it as a child into your `CardView`.

Comment: ok I will try it, I hope it will work

Comment: @pelya I tried it but I can't handle it can you give me a sample or tell how can add animation as a child to cardView?